# Moving a Wordpress Page on a Multisite Setup

Tags: wordpress, subdomain, multisite

I made a Wordpress page on my domain i.e. `www.example.com/supercoolpage`.

Then I learned about Wordpress Multisites and set that up, how do I move that page to `supercoolpage.example.com`?

I really don’t want to rebuild it, and I want to redesign my main domain.

Comment: You can export the content from one child site and import into another child site

Comment: This is not a programming question so you are offtopic here, you will find better help in [Webmasters.se]

Comment: @dipmala broke a few things but that did the trick, thanks!